# Modify IEnumerable function

Tags: c#, linq, ienumerable

I have next code:

```
 public sealed class Gaaa
        {
            private readonly int _ids;

            public Gaaa(int id)
            {
                _ids = id;
            }
            public static IEnumerable<Gaaa> Generate(int num)
            {
                return Enumerable.Range(1, num).Select(ids => new Gaaa(ids + 1));
            }
        }
```

How can I represent the code differently in the Generate function?

Comment: What do you mean "differently"? Do you mean not using the dot notation but using the more wordy version?

Comment: @Sweeper, yes I want using the more wordy version or otherwise

Comment: There's literally an infinite number of ways you could modify the function to be different. Please be specific in your questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you don't like the dot notation. Here is how you do it:

```
return from id in Enumerable.Range(1, num)
    select new Gaaa(id + 1);
```

I personally prefer the dot notation here because what you are trying to do is so simple - creating a bunch of `Gaaa`s with an incrementing range. I think it's more readable to use the dot notation in this particular case.

Query notation, I think, is more suitable to be used in situations involving collections and more complicated operations like this:

```
from item in aCollection
where item.Property2 > 10
orderby item.Property1
select item.Property3
```

Also, query notation is particularly more readable when doing a join.